# Magento 2: Search Result inappropriate

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, search, catalogsearch, search-terms

I am using Magento 2.3.3 in which I have products with name like DR. Aqua guard. Whenever Customer search using a query like "DR." It showing result from product name contains "DR" in names like "H2GO DRINKING WATER BOTTLE–SINGLE" Rather than Result of those products start with "DR.".

> **Execpted Result:**

[image]

> **Actual Result:**

[image]

Any clue on this please. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Magento by default uses the MySql based search. So, it is split text on word on by pattern.
It will show all the products with DR in the name.

Comment: Thank you for replying,  Can we customize it ?

Comment: Yes you can or you can use extension for that.

Comment: Can you suggest extension? or can we switch to ealstic search to get result?

Comment: Elastic Search is recommended . But look for another module which will suitable for you

Comment: Okay. Thanks...